# How can I store a subshell PID in a variable so that I can kill the subshell and its background process later?

Tags: bash, shell, process, pid, subshell

So, let us say I am running a subshell with a background process as follows:

```bash
(command &)
```

I want to be able to store the PID of this subprocess into a bash variable so that I can kill the subshell and its running background process later. How can I do so?

Note: This may very well be a duplicate, but I am struggling to implement many of the other answers. So, even if this question is marked as a duplicate, I would appreciate it if someone could still provide an answer regardless.

Some things I have tried:

```bash
pid="$((echo "$BASHPID" && command &))"
pid2="$((command & echo "$BASHPID"))"
pid3=(echo "$BASHPID" && command &)
pid4=(command & echo "$BASHPID")
```

Comment: is there a reason you're using `(command &)` instead of `command &`? I'm not suggesting your approach is right or wrong, just curious as to the reason why you picked this approach?

Comment: @markp-fuso I have added some attempts as recommended. The reason I am using a subshell in the first place is to suppress background-process related output (e.g. `[1] <pid>` and `[1]+  Terminated: 15          <command>`)

Comment: `in the first place is to suppress background-process related output` ? There is no background output _in scripts_. Maybe just `set +m`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am a bit confused what you mean. In this case, the aforementioned background-process output occurs if I do not use a subshell. To clarify, this is for a function that I put in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: You are confusing command substitution (`$(...)`) with arithmetic expressions (`$((...))`).

Comment: @chepner Ah, I forgot about that syntax. I was foolishly trying to create a subshell in a command substitution expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea:

```
$ read -r x < <(sleep 240 & echo $!)       # alternative: replace $! with $BASHPID
                ^^^^^^^^^        ^^    
$ echo "$x"
1887
^^^^
$ ps -aef|egrep sleep
myuser    1887       1 pty1     16:00:17 /usr/bin/sleep
          ^^^^                                    ^^^^^
$ pgrep -a sleep
1887 sleep 240
^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: But that will hide the output. You could do `exec 3>&1; read pid < <(sleep 240 >&3 & echo $!)` so that the background command can still write to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication . For example use a fifo:

```
pidfile=$(mktemp -n)
mkfifo "$pidfile"
(command & echo $! > "$pidfile")
read pid < "$pidfile"
rm "$pidfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the shortest way of achieving it is using `coproc`:

```
#! /bin/bash

coproc ./mycommand
pid=$COPROC_PID
```